Configuring SQUID Proxy for authentication, global access, and user-specific logging
I am looking for some guidance on setting up a SQUID proxy server on Ubuntu with the following conditions:

Access should be restricted to authenticated users listed in /etc/squid/passwords, it is achieved by:

auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords

users are added via
sudo htpasswd /etc/squid/passwords username


The proxy should allow access from any location worldwide (which line in the config file controls this? I suspect that http_access deny and http_access allow settings might be conflicting and I ask for help with this one particularly).
The proxy should only handle HTTP and HTTPS traffic, excluding other protocols (I believe ACL settings control this).
Logging should be user-specific based on /etc/squid/passwords to monitor individual user activity (what does "combined" mean in this context?):

access_log /var/log/squid/access.log combined

I would like to create a minimalistic config file to meet these requirements, but whenever I manage to fulfill one requirement from the list, another one stops working, and so on. It's driving me crazy... Thanks in advance!


Your configuration is correct.
By default, if no restrictions are specified, access will be permitted from any IP address.
acl Safe_ports port 80, acl Safe_ports port 443 and acl Safe_ports port 443
Unfortunately, logging cannot be split into separate files per user, but you can have the username from /etc/squid/passwords as the first column in the log to make it easy to visually separate. If that's not enough, you can write a custom script to split the log file into separate files by username.

Here's a minimal config that should satisfy your requirements:
# Basic Access Control Lists (ACLs)
acl all src all
acl SSL_ports port 443         # Allow only HTTPS on port 443
acl Safe_ports port 443        # Allow only HTTPS on port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80         # Allow only HTTP on port 80

# Basic authentication settings
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords
auth_param basic realm "Enter username and password"
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED

# HTTP access control
http_access allow authenticated   # Allow access only if authenticated
http_access deny all              # Deny all other access

# HTTP port configuration
http_port 3128

# Logs (%un is for an username from the /etc/squid/passwords)
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log custom_combined
logformat custom_combined %un %>a [%{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}tl] "%rm %ru HTTP/%rv" %Hs %<st "%{User-Agent}>h" "%{Referer}>h"

